# Prevent destruction of self after main?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, memory-leaks, stl

I'm writing some asynchronous I/O stuff in C++, and I need to prevent an object from being destructed until its handler for the asynchronous I/O is called. I'm trying to use `shared_ptr` and create my object with a static constructor so I can be sure that it is using reference counting. Then I save that in a `weak_ptr` until I start the asynchronous I/O, when I store it into another `shared_ptr` to be sure it doesn't become invalid during that time. Finally, I reset it when the callback completes. Here's an example:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class SomeIO {
    std::weak_ptr<SomeIO> self;
    std::shared_ptr<SomeIO> savingSelf;

    void myCallback() {
        // do my callback stuff here
        savingSelf.reset();
    }
public:
    SomeIO() = delete;
    ~SomeIO() {}

    static shared_ptr<SomeIO> create() {
        auto self = make_shared<SomeIO>();
        self->self = self;
        return self;
    }

    void start() {
        savingSelf = self.lock();
        //startSomeAsyncIO(bind(self, SomeIO::myCallback));
    }
};

int main() {
    auto myIO = SomeIO::create();

    myIO->start();

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, what is going to happen after main returns? Will it stay alive until the final reference is released, or is this going to cause a memory leak? If this does cause a memory leak, how do I handle this situation so the asynchronous I/O can be canceled and the program can end without a memory leak? I would think that `shared_ptr` protects me from memory leaks, but I'm not so sure about this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: You should phrase it differently: what should happen when main returns? Does it make sense for an asynchronous operation to be left unfinished? Who would take care of cleaning it up?

Comment: Do you just want to run your `myCallback()` function asynchronously until its finished?

Comment: Hmmm, it'd have to to wait for and dispatch the event, for example with an `epoll` call on Linux. I think you're right though, because that means that this HAS to be linked to an event loop anyways, and I can prevent the ending of the program in that eventloop until it has dispatched all pending events. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @Galik the idea is that `startSomeAsyncIO` starts a process eventually call myCallback somewhere else, so it won't be running myCallback until after it is finished.

Comment: Does `startSomeAsyncIO()` block or return immediately?

Comment: @Galik I would assume it returns immediately, hence the word "asynchronous"...

Comment: I don't understand why this should create a memory leak, unless you are dealing with a very special operating system that does not release all memory when a process terminates. It's just one object which is *by design* supposed to live as long as the program. That means you don't use a smart pointer; you create it with `new` and never delete it. It's a memory leak only if, for example, the number of instances depends on user input and grows over time.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ (as opposed to Java) , the program ends whenever the main ends. all other threads are terminated. memory leaks are not your problem since the program ends anyway and all the memory is deallocated.

you can use std::thread with std::thread::join to prevent you program from exiting too early :

```
int main (void){

std::thread myAsyncIOThread ([]{
    auto myIO = SomeIO::create();
    myIO->start();
});

//other things you program needs to do
myAsyncIOThread.join();
return 0;
}
```

you might want to be interested having a Thread-Pool in your program.